# What is the main differance between .so file and .jar android

Tags: android, static-libraries, android-library

What is the main difference between .so file and .jar file in android? 
Is it possible to change using of .so with using of .jar file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079230/what-exactly-does-a-jar-file-contain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.so are **S**hared **O**bjects are linked during the runtime. If there are any changes in your .so you dont need to recompile. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files)

.jar are **J**ava **Ar**hive files -fundamental archive files, built on the ZIP file format. They can contain anything:classes,images,text [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format))

Answer (score 1):

[.so files](http://file.org/extension/so) are typically C or C++ libraries, while [.jar files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html) are a zip-format archive used for Java.

Also, could you explain the second part more? What do you want to do?

Comment: i need to import so file in my xamarin project. honestly I try to use C4000 china device's barcode reader in xamarin. In documentation second step is : Put libDeviceAPI.so file to the directory \libs\armeabi\. (operation system is android, demo code is written in android studio)